# Recognize form submission action by anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

■ BACKGROUND:

I have an html like below, which has 1 button, 2 anchors, and a input to hold value wrapped in a form.
The goal i want to achieve is:

1. be able to submit the form no matter from clicking both button and Anchor.
2. using post.
3. be able to recognized which element causes a submit.(e.g. button id or anchor id)

■ ISSUE:

The problem I am facing is that "since anchors are not focusable, the $(document.activeElement) will not recognize it if submits are triggerred
by clicking anchors" (learned from google result...).

■ QUESTION:

So, are there any easy(less changes to my current code) alternative ways to achieve my goal or simply how to recognize submission from anchors so that I can possibly capture its information just like what I 
can do for button submission in this case?

thanks

```html
<form id="detailsForm" method="post" class="ui form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="someUrl">

...
<button id="prodDelButton" form="detailsForm">
delete
</button>
...
<input type="text" id="pickupSearchCriteria.pageNumber" name="pickupSearchCriteria.pageNumber" value="1" />

<a class="item paginationAnchor" id="1" onclick="document.getElementById('detailsForm').submit();" shape="rect">page1</a>
<a class="item paginationAnchor" id="2" onclick="document.getElementById('detailsForm').submit();" shape="rect">page2</a>
...
...
</form>


...

<script id="shared_index_before">
    $('#detailsForm').submit(function () {

        var $btn = $(document.activeElement);
        if ($btn.prop('id') == 'stgDelButton') {
            $("#pickupSearchCriteria.pageNumber").val($btn.prop('id'));
        }
        else if ($btn.prop('id') == 'prodDelButton') {
            $("#pickupSearchCriteria.pageNumber").val($btn.prop('id'));
        }
        else if($btn.hasClass( "paginationAnchor" )){
            
            $("#pickupSearchCriteria.pageNumber").val($btn.prop('id'));
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't rely on the active element, and don't call the submission directly. Create an event listener for the clicks, extract the needed information from the event object, and then call a function that will submit the actual form. You might wanna do a preventDefault() on the form submission, in order to handle this whole thing manually. Hope i understood your problem correctly.

Comment: @sheff2k1 thanks for your quick comment. I don't have much experience with javascript, but I think what you described makes sense, I'd really appreciate if your can share a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="detailsForm" method="post" class="ui form" enctype="application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded" action="someUrl">

   <button class="submitableElement" id="prodDelButton" >
     delete
   </button>

   <input type="text" id="pickupSearchCriteria.pageNumber"name="pickupSearchCriteria.pageNumber" value="1" />

   <a class="item paginationAnchor submitableElement" id="1"  shape="rect">page1</a>
   <a class="item paginationAnchor submitableElement" id="2"  shape="rect">page2</a>

</form>
```

The js:

```
$('.submitableElement').click(function(event){
   const id = event.target.id;
   doSomeThingWithId(id)//You can use the item id to know what was clicked.
   $('#detailsForm').submit()
 })



function doSomeThingWithId(id){
   alert(`Element with id ${id} was used to submit the form...`);  
   //Do something here with the data...
}
```

I think that this is more or less what you need, but i would recommend you to reconsider if what you're doing there is actually needed.

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ku4rgqne/